# Is there a proof that $\ln(3)>1$ that doesn't use the fact $3>e$ or that $e$ is irrational?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I tried to do this using the $y=\frac{1}{x}$ hyperbola, didn't get anywhere though, I did find other things though like $\ln(2)>\frac{1}{2}$ and $\ln(3)-\ln(2)<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The statement is the same as saying $\int_1^3 \frac{dx}{x} > 1$. You can try to bound the integral from below by e.g. dividing $[1,3]$ into $N$ equal pieces and doing the sum ($N=7$ should do... and I would use a computer to do the sum).

Comment: The answer depends on how you are defining the function $\ln$. Is it defined as the inverse of the map $x\mapsto e^x$, and if so, how are you defining $e^x$? Or perhaps you are using the definition $\ln x = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t} \, dt$? It would help if you edit your question for clarity.

Comment: I'm defining ln(x) as the integral you proposed

Comment: I'm also defining ln(x) as the inverse. Here's how I define e^x: For all solutions to y'=y the solutions are y=ce^x where c is a constant. From this follows the reciprocal of the factorials infinite summation for Euler's number and the fact Euler's number is the limit as x approaches infinity of (1+1/x)^x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1034520/42969)) to the strictly convex function $x \mapsto 1/x$ gives the lower bound
$$
 \ln (3) = \int_1^3 \frac{dx}{x}  > \frac{2}{(1+3)/2} = 1 \, .
$$

This inequality simply uses the fact that the graph of a convex function lies above any of its tangents, here the tangent at the point $(2, 1/2)$:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just divide the axis between 1 and 3 into 2n intervals of width 1/n. Since 1/t is decreasing, you get $1/t \geq 1/(1+k/n)$ on the interval $[1+(k-1)/n, 1+k/n]$ and thus
$$
\ln(3) = \int_1^3 {dt \over t} \geq  {1 \over n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} {1\over 1+{k\over n}} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} {1\over n+k}.
$$
For n = 4, the right sum is already bigger than 1. It is equal to 28721/27720.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Taylor series of the logarithm we get for $0 < x < 1$
$$
 \ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) = \ln(1+x) -\ln(1-x) 
= 2 \left( x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac 15 x^5 + \cdots \right) > 2x \, .
$$
Setting $x=1/2$ gives $\log(3) > 1$.

Comment: (+1) Hello @MartinR, I have an "elementary" proof using $e^x≥x+1$ . But I am not an expert in calculus, is this argument circular ?

Comment: @lonestudent: I don't know, it probably depends on how you show that $e^x \ge 1+x$, there are *many* proofs of that inequality: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663/42969

Comment: Good or bad, I have posted the proof.  It's a enough simple proof that can be done by anyone .

Answer (score 1):

We can also reach the proof by simply applying the well-known inequality $e^x≥x+1$ .

---

Using the substitution $x\longmapsto -\ln x,\thinspace x>0$ we have :

$$
\begin{align}&\frac 1x≥1-\ln x\\
\iff &\ln x≥1-\frac 1x \color{#c00}{\tag 1}\end{align}
$$

Equality occurs iff, when $x=1$ .

Then, we see that putting $x=3$ leads to :

$$
\begin{align}\ln 3>1-\frac 13=\frac 23\end{align}
$$

which is too weak .

Therefore, we want to multiply both side of the inequality $\color{#c00}{(1)}$ by $6$ and see if it works for us :

$$
\begin{align}&\ln x^6≥6-\frac 6x,\thinspace x>0\\
\iff &\ln x \overset{x\thinspace\longmapsto\thinspace\sqrt[6]{x}}{≥}6-\frac {6}{\sqrt [6]{x}}\end{align}
$$

Thus, it is enough to show that :

$$6-\frac {6}{\sqrt [6]{3}}>1$$

which is equivalent to :

$$
\begin{align}&3>\left(\frac 65\right)^6\\
\iff &5^6>2\cdot 6^5\\
\iff &15625>15552 \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ at $x=1$:

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}\mp...$$

The radius of convergence is $|x|<1$, so $x=2$ won't do. However, take $x=-\frac{2}{3}$, then

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{9}-\frac{8}{81}-\frac{4}{81}-...<-1$$

where the first four terms are enough to dip below $-1$. Therefore, $\ln(3)=-\ln\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)>1$.

*If you are starting from the integral definition for the natural logarithm, you can of course derive the Taylor series around $1$ by integrating the geometric series $\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n$.*

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\ln(3)
&= \frac{⅔^1}{1} + \frac{⅔^2}{2} + \frac{⅔^3}{3} + \frac{⅔^4}{4} + ⋯\\
&> \frac{⅔^1}{1} + \frac{⅔^2}{2} + \frac{⅔^3}{3} + \frac{⅔^4}{4}\\
&= 1.037037037037⋯\\
&> 1.
\end{align}$$